# Почему не грузится скрипт?

Tags: html, angularjs, spring-boot

Скрипт, который закомментирован, грузится. А с bower_components не грузится.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./bower_components/bootstrap-css-only/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div class="container" ng-controller="AppController">
       <div class="page-header">
        <h1>A checklist</h1>
       </div>
       <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert" ng-hide="items &amp;&amp; items.length > 0">
        There are no items yet.
      </div>
       <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" ng-submit="addItem(newItem)">
          <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="item in items">
             <div class="checkbox col-xs-9">
                <label>
                   <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.checked" ng-change="updateItem(item)"/> {{item.description}}
                </label>
             </div>
             <div class="col-xs-3">
                <button class="pull-right btn btn-danger" type="button" title="Delete"
                             ng-click="deleteItem(item)">
                   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                </button>
             </div>
          </div>
          <hr />
          <div class="input-group">
             <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="newItem" placeholder="Enter the description..." />
             <span class="input-group-btn">
              <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" ng-disabled="!newItem" title="Add">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
              </button>
             </span>
          </div> 
       </form>

    </div>

    <!--script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js">
        </script-->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="./bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./bower_components/lodash/dist/lodash.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./app/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Если вам нужно пойти в дерикторию назад, тогда надо сделать ../ (С двумя точками)
В вашем случае оно с одной точкой

Comment: Разобрался. Спасибо.